# Filter data from array in array mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have this data structure:

```
{
  date: 0,
  darwin: [
    {
      d: ['string1', 1, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      d: ['string2', 1, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    {
      d: ['string3', 1, 0, 0, 0]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const dataSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Number, required: false, unique: true, index: true },
  humanDate: { type: Date, required: false },
  darwin: [
    {
      d: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
      }
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('data', dataSchema);
```

I need a list of strings inside "d", i try this

```
db.getCollection('data').find({date:0},{'darwin.d.$': 1})
```

but i have this error

```
Error: error: {
"operationTime" : Timestamp(1635348468, 1),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "positional operator '.$' couldn't find a matching element in the array",
"code" : 51246,
"codeName" : "Location51246",
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1635348468, 1),
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : BinData(0,"pfgMUIJkpgjlfnQ6cfiEDpSY+3o="),
        "keyId" : NumberLong("7020434099001098244")
    }
}}
```

I have tried several things but I can't get it to get the list of strings, I don't know if I'm applying the '$' operator wrong

I expected some like this

```
{
  date: 0,
  darwin: [
    {
      d: 'string1'
    },
    {
      d: 'string2'
    },
    {
      d: 'string3'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate method like this:

- First `$match` the docuemnts where `date` has the desired value
- Then `$project` to map over the array and get values you want: For each element in `darwin` array get the first element in `d` array using `$arrayElemAt`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "date": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "date": 1,
      "darwin": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$darwin",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "d": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$m.d",
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Which output is:

```
[
  {
    "darwin": [
      {
        "d": "string1"
      },
      {
        "d": "string2"
      },
      {
        "d": "string3"
      }
    ],
    "date": 0
  }
]
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wAZ7URcMt94)